# Ler texto em um local especifico da imagem

Tags: python, ocr

Preciso de ajuda para tentar ler um texto em uma parte especifica da imagem.
O intuito é identificar um produto especifico dentre vários iguais, porém a única coisa que muda é o texto presente nele.

Estou fazendo o reconhecimento de um objeto e pegando a posição dele na imagem:

Imagem de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Posição:
[727 1378 2852 1957]

Tentei utilizar o OCR, mas não consegui passar como o vetor como parâmetro.

OBS:
Preciso identificar o texto apenas dentro desse quadrado(rosa), por isso a utilização desse vetor.

**É possível, utilizando OCR? 
Se sim, como eu faço isso? 
Se Não, há outra opção?**

Answer (score -1):

Opa amigo blz ? fiz algo para te ajudar mas não ficou muito bom, mas mesmo assim irei postar aqui para te dar um norte para seguir

```
from pytesseract import Output
import pytesseract
import cv2


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'D:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Temp\uno.jpg')
image = cv2.detailEnhance(image[220:1400 , 610:940], sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)

#convertendo imagem em imagem em escala de cinza 
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# convertendo para imagem binária por Thresholding 
# este passo é necessário se você tiver uma imagem colorida porque se você pular esta parte 
# então o tesseract não conseguirá detectar o texto corretamente e isso dará um resultado incorreto 
threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# agora alimentando imagem para tesseract 
details = pytesseract.image_to_data(threshold_img, output_type=Output.DICT)
for i in range(len(details['text'])):
    text = details['text'][i]
    print(text)

cv2.imshow(f"Original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```